# Putting text and some basic animation in an arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am pretty new to D3 but i have a basic knowledge of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. And i was tasked to create a dashboard for our team in MS Sharepoint (used to be in Excel lol).

Right now, i only need 6 Arcs to be visually presented in the site page. I can just extract the data lists from sharepoint and compute it via javascript then store it in a variable to throw it in the D3 arc. Here is my current code:

```
<body>

    <div class="container" id="graph_container1">
        <svg id="svg1"></svg>
        <svg id="svg2"></svg>
        <svg id="svg3"></svg>
    </div>

    <script>

            var canvas = d3.select("#svg1")
                        .attr("width", 400)
                        .attr("height", 400);

            var group = canvas.append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(150, 150)");

            var r = 100;
            var p = Math.PI * 2;
            var score = 70;
            var finalScore = p * (70/100);

            var arc = d3.arc()
                    .innerRadius(r)
                    .outerRadius(80)
                    .startAngle(0)
                    .endAngle(finalScore);

            group.append("path").attr("d", arc)
                                .attr("fill", "orange")
                                .transition()
                                .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                                .duration(2000)
                                .attrTween("d", pieTween);

            function pieTween(b) {          
                b.innerRadius = 0;
                var i = d3.interpolate( {startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b );
                return function(t) { return arc(i(t));};            
            }


    </script>

</body>
```

I have 3 main problems right now:

1. Putting the score text in the middle of the Arc graph
2. Making a simple animation for the Arc graph like filling up the graph until to the final score
3. Creating 5 more graphs just like those

I am copying this animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kK5kKA-0PUQ. I tried its code but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since in a pie/donut chart there is normally one group translated to the center of the chart (which is the case here), just append a text using `text-anchor` as `middle` (here, using just 2 decimal places):

   ```
   group.append("text")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text(d3.format(".2f")(finalScore))
   ```
2. Your `pieTween` function has a parameter (`b`), but there is no argument being passed, since there is no data bound. Besides that, the arc generator has `finalScore` as the end angle, and because of that no transition is possible.

   Change the arc generator and the `pieTween` function accordingly:

   ```
   var arc = d3.arc()
       .innerRadius(r)
       .outerRadius(80)
       .startAngle(0);

   function pieTween() {
       var i = d3.interpolate({
           endAngle: 0
       }, {
           endAngle: finalScore
       });
       return function(t) {
           return arc(i(t));
       };
   }
   ```
3. Too broad for S.O., sounds like a request. Try it yourself and, if you can't, ask another question (sharing the non-working code).

Here is the code with those changes:

```html
<body>

  <div class="container" id="graph_container1">
    <svg id="svg1"></svg>
    <svg id="svg2"></svg>
    <svg id="svg3"></svg>
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var canvas = d3.select("#svg1")
      .attr("width", 400)
      .attr("height", 400);

    var group = canvas.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(150, 150)");

    var r = 100;
    var p = Math.PI * 2;
    var score = 70;
    var finalScore = p * (70 / 100);

    var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(r)
      .outerRadius(80)
      .startAngle(0);

    group.append("path")
      .attr("fill", "orange")
      .transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(2000)
      .attrTween("d", pieTween);

    group.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(d3.format(".2f")(finalScore))

    function pieTween() {
      var i = d3.interpolate({
        endAngle: 0
      }, {
        endAngle: finalScore
      });
      return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
      };
    }

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked! Also, thank you for explaining the step by step of it, i learned a lot from that. 

Regarding the #3, sorry if sounded like a request. What i am asking is, if i will create another copy of those Arcs, should i copy and paste the code from the canvas up to group.append("text")?

Comment: @VinceCantuba Yes, but with different variables. The best idea, regarding code duplication, is creating a function to draw those different SVGs.

Comment: Can i ask again? i have this graphs and code now: https://jsfiddle.net/moqvfj65/17/

1. I want to format my middle numbers to %. How can i do that with my current code?

2. How can i append a text below my arc chart? I want to put a description there with enough spacing since this will be used in a dashboard.

3. How can i change the font size and style of the texts?

Thanks again!

Comment: Please, don't make questions in the comments section, there is no place to answer them: just post a *new* question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000719/d3-js-adding-and-customizing-texts-in-a-graph